# What library to use for XML SOAP Dispatching

Tags: c#, java

At my last place we used to do a lot via XML SOAP - Basically the client would construct an XML request which would contain the service to invoke and send that onto a host and port

The server would then take that service request and figure out the class and method to call and serialise the request / response

This was helpful as we had Java and C# and wanted to segregate the two

If you had to build this out what libraries would you use?

Specifically how the main machine translates a service name => class and method invocation

Answer (score 1):

In C# I'd look at [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) in the first instance, that allows you to create web services very simply.

Comment: Is what I am trying to do called a web service?

Comment: As Flanders might say, "Yes indeedy-doody it is!"

Answer (score 1):

For Java, I have experience with [axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) from Apache.  It works well enough that I would recommend it and use it again on a SOAP project.